# Output prompts are on top of each other

Tags: common-lisp

I am reading the book *Practical Common Lisp*. I typed the simple CD database shown in Chapter 3. See below. When I run the `(add-cds)` program the result is a prompt containing two prompts on top of each other (more precisely, one prompt after another, on the same line):

```
(add-cds)
=> Title: Artist:
```

Why is it doing this? The program should give me the `Title:` prompt first and the `Artist:` prompt only after I've typed in a value for `Title:` followed by newline. I am pretty sure that I typed in the program faithfully. How do I fix this?

```
(defvar *db* nil)

(defun make-cd (title artist rating ripped)
  (list :title title :artist artist :rating rating :ripped ripped))

(defun add-record (cd) (push cd *db*))

(defun prompt-read (prompt)
  (format *query-io* "~a: " prompt)
  (force-output *query-io*)
  (read-line *query-io*))

(defun prompt-for-cd ()
  (make-cd
    (prompt-read "Title")
    (prompt-read "Artist")
    (or (parse-integer (prompt-read "Rating") :junk-allowed t) 0)
    (y-or-n-p "Ripped [y/n]")))

(defun add-cds ()
  (loop (add-record (prompt-for-cd))
      (if (not (y-or-n-p "Another? [y/n]: ")) (return))))
```

Comment: Works fine for me with SBCL on OS X. What implementation are you using, and on which OS?

Comment: I am using LispIDE on Windows 10.

Comment: Works fine also on CCL.

Answer (score 3):

What's happening is that the newline after `(add-cds)` is being left in the input stream (because the REPL stops reading as soon as it sees the matching close parenthesis), so the first `read-line` is reading that as a blank line and returning immediately. Call `clear-input` before calling `read-line` to ignore this and wait for new input.

```
(defun prompt-read (prompt)
  (format *query-io* "~a: " prompt)
  (force-output *query-io*)
  (clear-input *query-io*)
  (read-line *query-io*))
```

Comment: Thanks, but adding that clear-input had no impact. I'm thinking that there is a bug in LispIDE.

Comment: You could try using a loop that repeats if the input is an empty string.